# Which App is on the foreground?

Tags: java, android

Can I know somehow which App is on the foreground at the moment if I'm using Background Service or Broadcast Receiver maybe by having its package name? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html).

```
ActivityManager mManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(UpdateService.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> myTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);

ForegroundActivity => myTasks.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
```